# If a bug is fixed on the master branch but hasn't been released on npm, how can I incorporate the fix into my project?

Tags: javascript, npm

A library that we're using has merged a critical bug fix, but it hasn't been released as a new version on npm. How can we pull down the new change?

Comment: Can you please include more details on the project and the npm package you are talking? I believe you can just simply cherry pick it, or may be not?

Comment: check out the repository, copy the required sources over to some folder in your web-app and include it from there. (subject to the source structure of the library in question)

Comment: You can can copy/paste the code into the files in your `node_modules`. You can use `git+https://blahblahproject` to pull the dependency directly from github. You can manually clone the repo, rebuild locally, and deploy. Note that these are all dirty hacks.

Comment: Seriously not sure how NPM documentation on using unreleased repos as dependencies was skipped over in favor of "guess and pray, then go around the built in features for this use case" as an accepted answer. I don't even want the rep, I just think it's harmful to those seeking an answer to this problem.

Comment: @gelliott181 my bad, i meant to downvote that answer but instead gave it the checkmark. should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NPM Docs for Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

> Git urls can be of the form:

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```